# android-studio can't use "lvl library" because gradle namespace error

Tags: android, gradle, namespaces

I'm developing an app with AndroidStudio and would now like to integrate Google's lvl_library. So far everything is good, but unfortunately grandle has a problem with the namespace of this labrary.

The following error is issued:

```
Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.
```

I have already carried out the AGP upgrade.

I've already searched the internet, but everything fails.

can someone help me ?

settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Kontakt Auswahl pro"
include ':app'
include ':lvl_library'
```

biuld.gradle from the lvl_library:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 4
        //noinspection ExpiredTargetSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.5"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml from the lvl_library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.vending.licensing">
    <!-- Devices >= 3 have version of Android Market that supports licensing. -->
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <!-- Required permission to check licensing. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
</manifest>
```